# How to calculate the probability of this summation?

Tags: probability

I have $n$ points generated uniformly at random in a square of size $10m\times 10m$. The random variable $X_i$ is given by

$$
X_i\triangleq\left(\dfrac{1}{d_i}\right)^2, \forall\,i=1,\ldots,n
$$
where $d_i$ is the distance to the origin of points $i$. See Figure. 1 below.

[image]

Let $a>0$, I would like to know if there is any way to find this probability?

$$\Pr\left[\sum_{i'\neq i}X_{i'}\leqslant aX_i-1\right].$$

If $n=2$ and $d_i\triangleq\sqrt{x_i^2+y_i^2}$, then I have to calculate

$$\begin{align}
\Pr\left[X_{i'}\leqslant aX_i-1\right]&=\Pr\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{d_{i'}}\right)^2\leqslant a\left(\dfrac{1}{d_i}\right)^2-1\right],\\
&=\Pr\left[\dfrac{a}{d_{i}^2}\geqslant 1+\dfrac{1}{d_{i'}^2}\right],\\
&=\Pr\left[\dfrac{a}{x_i^2+y_i^2}\geqslant 1+\dfrac{1}{x_{i'}^2+y_{i'}^2}\right].
\end{align}$$
Here  $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the coordinates of the point $i$ which are uniformly distributed $\mathcal{U}(-5, 5)$.

Even for $n=2$ I cannot continue. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: This is not a complete answer. Just for illustrations of some calculations.**

For the exact form, even $n = 2$ will be tedious and may not be possible to have the closed-form solution.

Let $X, Y \sim \mathcal{U}(-\theta, \theta)$ and they are independent. First we find out the pdf of $W = X^2$. Note for $w \in (0, \theta^2)$, the CDF of $W$

$$ F_W(w) = \Pr\{X^2 \leq w\} = \Pr\{-\sqrt{w} \leq X \leq \sqrt{w}\} 
= \frac {2\sqrt{w}} {2\theta} = \frac {\sqrt{w}} {\theta}$$

Hence the pdf is

$$ f_W(w) = \frac {1} {2\theta\sqrt{w}}, w \in (0, \theta^2)$$

Next let $V = Y^2$ which has the same distribution as $W$. By convolution, the pdf of $Z = W + V$ is

$$ f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_V(z-w)f_W(w)dw$$

From the above result, we know that $f_W(w) > 0 \iff 0 < w < \theta^2$ and
$ f_V(z-w) > 0 \iff 0 < z - w < \theta^2 \iff z - \theta^2 < w < z$. Hence,

$$ \begin{align} f_Z(z) &= \int_{\max\{0, z-\theta^2\}}^{\min\{\theta^2, z\}} 
\frac {1} {2\theta\sqrt{z-w}}\frac {1} {2\theta\sqrt{w}} dw \\
&=  \left. \frac {1} {2\theta^2}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac {w} {z-w}}\right|_{\max\{0, z-\theta^2\}}^{\min\{\theta^2, z\}} \\
&= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac {\pi} {4\theta^2} & \text{if} & 0 < z < \theta^2 \\
\displaystyle \frac {\pi} {4\theta^2} - \frac {1} {\theta^2} \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac {z- \theta^2} {\theta^2}} 
& \text{if} & \theta^2 < z < 2\theta^2 \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

So we obtain the pdf of $D^2$. Now let $R$ be another point's square distance from origin, which is i.i.d. as $Z$. The required probability becomes
$$ \begin{align} \Pr\left\{\frac {1} {R} \leq \frac {a} {Z} - 1\right\}
&= \Pr\left\{Z \leq \frac {a} {\frac {1} {R} + 1}\right\} \\
&= \int_0^{2\theta^2} \Pr\left\{Z \leq \frac {ra} {1 + r}\right\} f_R(r)dr
\end{align}$$

Note $\displaystyle \frac {ra} {1 + r} $ is increasing with $r$, so for $0 < r < 2\theta^2$,

$$0 < \frac {ra} {1 + r} < \frac {2\theta^2 a} {1 + 2\theta^2} $$

For $\displaystyle 0 < \frac {2\theta^2 a} {1 + 2\theta^2} \leq \theta^2 \iff 0 \leq a \leq \frac {1} {2} + \theta^2$, we have

$$ \Pr\left\{Z \leq \frac {ra} {1 + r}\right\} 
= \frac {\pi} {4\theta^2} \frac {ra} {1 + r}$$

and thus the above probability become

$$ \begin{align} 
&~ \int_0^{\theta^2} \frac {\pi} {4\theta^2} \frac {ra} {1 + r}  
\frac {\pi} {4\theta^2}dr 
+ \int_{\theta^2}^{2\theta^2} \frac {\pi} {4\theta^2} \frac {ra} {1 + r}
\left(\frac {\pi} {4\theta^2} - \frac {1} {\theta^2} 
\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac {r- \theta^2} {\theta^2}}\right)dr \\
=&~ \frac {a\pi^2} {16a\theta^4} [2\theta^2 - \ln (2\theta^2 + 1)]
- \frac {a\pi} {4\theta^4} \int_{\theta^2}^{2\theta^2} \frac {r} {1+ r} \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac {r - \theta^2} {\theta^2}}dr 
\end{align}$$

but the latter integral should not have elementary closed-form solution to that, so the whole problem has to be relied on numerical solution. When $n$ is large, you may try to use CLT for an approximated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For n=2, since $d_1^2<50$ if $a<\frac{51}2$ then $d_2^2\le \frac a {1+\frac 1 {d_1^2}}<25$ will be always a circle. For $a>\frac{51}2$, in some cases, wanted area looks like on the image so I will cover only the first case

[image]

So now, for every possible value of $d_1$ we should calculate the probability that given inequality stands, and integrate it. We can examine just an eighth of the square

[image]

Let $\theta$ goes from 0 to $\pi/4$ and r goes from 0 to $\frac 5{\cos \theta}$

$P=\frac 8 {100}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\frac 5{\cos \theta}}\frac a {1+\frac 1 {r^2}}\frac{\pi}{100}rdrd\theta$
$=\frac {4a\pi} {10000}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\frac {25}{\cos^2 \theta}}\frac t {1+t}dtd\theta$
$=\frac {4a\pi} {10000}\int_0^{\pi/4}(t-\ln|1+t|)_0^{\frac {25}{\cos^2 \theta}}d\theta$
$=\frac {4a\pi} {10000}\int_0^{\pi/4}(\frac {25}{\cos^2 \theta}-\ln|1+\frac {25}{\cos^2 \theta}|)d\theta$
$=\frac {4a\pi} {10000}[(25\tan \theta-\theta\ln|1+\frac {25}{\cos^2 \theta}|)_0^{\pi/4}+\int_0^{\pi/4}\theta\frac 1 {1+\frac {25}{\cos^2 \theta}}\frac{50\sin \theta}{\cos^3 \theta}d\theta]$
$=\frac {4a\pi} {10000}[25-\frac \pi 4\ln51+50\int_0^{\pi/4}\theta\frac 1 {25+cos^2 \theta}\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}d\theta]$

So this was the easier integral, and so hard to solve it, it complicates a bit when $a>\frac{51}2$ and of course when $n>2$. Generally those geometrical probability problems are usually brutal, although they seem nice when you face them...